# Как правильно создать объект в объекте и создать для него свойства ? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, объекты

Помогите найти ошибку.

```js
var friends = new Object();

friends.steve = new Object();
steve.firstName = "Steve";
steve.lastName = "Jobs";
steve.number = "20-456-88";
steve.address = "Apple";

friends.bill = new Object();
bill.firstName = "Bill";
bill.lastName = "gates";
bill.number = "20-456-88";
bill.address = "Windows";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дошло. Глупо было спрашивать.

```js
var friends = new Object();

friends.steve = new Object();
friends.steve.firstName = "Steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "Jobs";
friends.steve.number = "20-456-88";
friends.steve.address = "Apple";

friends.bill = new Object();
friends.bill.firstName = "Bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "gates";
friends.bill.number = "20-456-88";
friends.bill.address = "Windows";
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так еще можно:

```
var friends = {
  steve: {
    firstName: "Steve",
    // ...
  },

  bill : {
    // ...
  },
}
```